# Powers of complex numbers property

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I would like to prove the following statement.

Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_s \in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $|\lambda_1| = \dots = |\lambda_s|=1$. Then $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0$ there exist arbitrarily large integers $n$ such that $|\lambda_1^n+\dots+\lambda_s^n| \geq s-\varepsilon$.

I don't really know how to start. I've tried the following approach.

Write $\lambda_i = e^{i\alpha_i}$, then we want to find arbitrarily large integers $n$ such that $n\alpha_i \approx 2k\pi$ for some integer $k$ for all $i$. The problem is that I don't know how to make "$\approx$" rigorous and how to find those integers $n$.

Comment: if $\alpha_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\alpha_k=0, k=2,3,\ldots,s$, can you still find such $n$ and $k_i$?

Comment: @Ali: $n=4m$, $k_1 = m$, $k_i=0$ for $i\neq1$.

Comment: @Meni: you are right :)

Comment: @mvcouwen : is this related to some other matrix analysis problem? For a second I thought it's expressing a bound on trace of a matrix power with all its eigenvalues on unit circle. I am sure I've seen something related in one of my matrix analysis books but I can't remember which one.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good; combined with a simple linear transformation it takes us from the realm of complex powers to the realm of multiplication modulo 1.

Start by proving a lemma: for every $\epsilon>0$ and 
$x \in [0,1)$ there is $n \in \mathbb{N}, n<\epsilon^{-1}$ such that $|nx|\le\epsilon \mod 1$.

Then, let $\epsilon>0$ and $x_1,\ldots, x_s \in [0,1)$. From now on I'll denote $f(m)=\epsilon^{2^m}$ simply because otherwise the display will be unintelligible.

Prove by induction on $i$ that there are natural numbers $n_1,\ldots, n_s$, so that for all $i$ you have:

1. $n_i < 1/f(s-i)$
2. For all $j\le i$, $|n_1\cdots n_i x_j|\le f(s-i) \mod 1$.

The base case for $i=1$ follows from the lemma above, for threshold $f(s-1)$.

For the induction step: Use the lemma on $x=n_1\cdots n_{i-1}x_i$ and threshold $f(s-i)$ to find $n_i<1/f(s-i)$ such that $n_1\cdots n_ix_i \le f(s-i)$. For $j<i$ you use the hypothesis. $|n_1\cdots n_{i-1} x_j|\le f(s-i+1)$, and $n_i < 1/f(s-i)$, so $|n_1\cdots n_{i} x_j|< f(s-i+1)/f(s-i) = \epsilon^{2^{s-i+1}-2^{s-i}} = \epsilon^{2^{s-i}}=f(s-i)$.

It follows that there is $n=n_1\cdots n_s < 1/f(2^s-1)$ such that $nx_i \le \epsilon$ for all $i$.

All that's left is to show you have arbitrarily large $n$ with this property, but that's trivial - simply pick a smaller $\epsilon$ and larger $n$.

Note: The intuition behind the proof is really very simple, and I hope it came across in this writeup. It took me 1 minute to come up with the idea, 15 minutes to work out the details and an hour to write it down...

Comment: I understand your proof but it still feels like if the main idea is hidden in the lemma. In the meantime, I came up with an own idea. Is it true that $lim_{k \to \infty} |\lambda_1^{n_k} + \dots + \lambda_s^{n_k}|=s$ where $n_k=\lfloor 10^k \frac{2\pi}{\alpha_1} \rfloor \dots \lfloor 10^k \frac{2\pi}{\alpha_s} \rfloor$?

Comment: @mvcouwen: I'm afraid it's not true. It fails even for $s=1$. You want to find $m$ such that $m\cdot2\pi/\alpha$ is as close to an integer as possible. $m=10^k$ won't help you - the initial decimal digits will convert to the integer part, but you're just extracting digits deeper and deeper from the decimal expansion, not approaching an integer. You need to find $m$ which is the denominator of a good rational approximation of $2\pi/\alpha$, such as one that can be obtained from a continued fraction expansion. This depends on the number and $10^k$ is not a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: @mvcouwen: As for my proof - the lemma is important, but I wouldn't call it the main idea because it's fairly obvious. You can easily prove a relaxed version of it which is sufficient for the rest of the proof (with some adjustments). The critical part is how to use the lemma multiple times with different thresholds to find a solution for multiple numbers simultaneously.

Comment: Am I right that the lemma follows from Dirichlet's approximation theorem? Is there an easier way to prove the lemma?

Comment: @mvcouwen: Exactly, in fact the two are virtually the same except for some terminology. You don't even need the DAT in all its glory - the idea of the proof holds if your lemma only says there is some $n<f(\epsilon)$ such that $|nx|<1$, you don't need to know that $f(\epsilon)=1/\epsilon$ (though that simplifies the expressions for the bounds in the rest of the proof). And the full DAT isn't hard to prove either. I do notice there's also a simultaneous version of DAT, which seems to immediately answer your question - with better bounds than in my method.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought that wanted to share : for every $\alpha_i$ we can find an integer $k_i$ such that $k_i \alpha_i \mbox{mod} (2\pi) \in I_\delta$ where $I_\delta = (-\delta, \delta)$  for an arbitrary small $\delta$ (Equidistribution modulo $2\pi$). 
Now if $n \ge m \; lcm(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_s)$ for an integer $m \ge 1$, then all $\beta_i = n \alpha_i \; \mbox{mod} ( 2\pi)$ are in $I_\delta$. 
So $\left|\sum{\lambda_k^n}\right| \ge s cos(\delta) = s - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon = s(1-cos(\delta))$.

Comment: I don't think $\beta_i \in I_{\delta}$ follows. You take a number in $I_{\delta}$, then multiply it by something, it's no longer in $I_{\delta}$.

Comment: @Meni: if for each $\alpha_i$ we find an arbitrary small $\delta_i$ then $\beta_i \in I_\delta = \cup{I_{\frac{n\delta_i}{k_i}}}$, does this solve this issue?

Comment: The smaller you want $\delta_i$ to be, the bigger the $k$'s need to be, so $n$ (a product of several $k$'s) becomes huge, and you don't have $n\delta_i/k_i <\delta$. I really think you need a more structured approach, carefully picking the $k_i$ and $\delta_i$, as in my answer. And even so, you definitely don't have "for all $n\ge\cdots$, if $n$ fits then $n+1$ won't fit.

Comment: Yes I agree, I probably need to spend more time to work out the details. But just a note, the statement is not asking "for all $n \ge \ldots$", the way I constructed $n$, the statement is true for $mn$ where $m \ge 1$,

Comment: Two problems: One, the statement does not ask for $n\ge\cdots$, but that is what you wrote. Two, if you revise it as $n = mn_0$ for $m \ge 1$, it's still not true - $n_0$ was found under the assumption of some threshold, if you multiply it by a large enough $m$ it will exceed the original threshold.